# Combine multiple paths into one in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I would like to combine paths from multiple match query. Consider a query

```
MATCH path_1 =  (t1:Type1)-[r1:]->(t2:Type2)
MATCH path_2 =  (t2)-[r2]->(t3:Type3) 
MATCH path_3 =  (t1)-[r3]->(t4:Type4)
RETURN path_1,path_2,path_3
```

1. How to combine all these three paths into one as like
   `apoc.path.combine(path_1,path_2) as path`, But it just combines two
   paths. I want to combine more than three paths.
2. How does Neo4j browser able to render a graph with the output given by above query?

Comment: You might be able to COLLECT the paths, and then call REDUCE on the resulting list: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce. You could then use apoc.path.combine in REDUCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions really, combine path or create path with APOC.

Given the following graph :

```
CREATE (p:Person {name: "John"})-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c:Company {name: "Acme"})
CREATE (c)-[:HAS_PHONE]->(pn:PhoneNumber {number : 123345})
CREATE (pn)<-[:PROVIDES]-(pr:TelcoProvider {name: "Vodafone"})
```

And the following query to retrieve paths :

```
MATCH p1=(p:Person)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c)
MATCH p2=(c)-[:HAS_PHONE]->(phone)
MATCH p3=(phone)-[r:PROVIDES]-(provider)
RETURN ...
```

**Combine Paths**

For this, you can use an accumulator starting with the first path, then reduce the remaining paths with `apoc.path.combine` :

```
MATCH p1=(p:Person)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(c)
MATCH p2=(c)-[:HAS_PHONE]->(phone)
MATCH p3=(phone)-[r:PROVIDES]-(provider)
WITH p1, [p2,p3] AS paths
RETURN reduce(acc = p1, x IN paths | apoc.path.combine(acc, x))
```

[image]

**Create Path**

The second solution is to create a path from the first node, and add all the relationships :

```
MATCH p1=(p:Person)-[r:WORKS_FOR]->(c)
MATCH p2=(c)-[r2:HAS_PHONE]->(phone)
MATCH p3=(phone)-[r3:PROVIDES]-(provider)
RETURN apoc.path.create(p, [r,r2,r3])
```

Which would yield the same result as above.